# Is the intersection of a sequence of nested subspaces nonempty?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Say $X$ is a topological space (compact). if $\{ A_n \} $ is a collection of nonempty closed subsets of $X$ such that $A_{n+1} \subseteq A_n $ for all $n$, then does it follow that $ \bigcap_n A_n $ is non-empty??

My try: Since $X$ is compact topological space and $A_n$'s are closed in $X$, then they must be compact. In particular, if $\mathcal{O}_{n}$ is open cover for each $A_n$, then can take open finite subcover $\{ O_{n,1}, ... , O_{n,k} \} $ for each of the $A_n's$. Since $A_{n+1} \subseteq A_n $ then this means that an open cover for $A_{n}$ is also an open cover for $A_{n+1}$ for all $n$. Im kinda of stuck here. Maybe I am taking the wrong route. Can someone help me? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved by using the [finite intersection property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_intersection_property) of compact spaces, that a space $X$ is compact iff for all collections $\mathscr{C}$ of closed sets in $X$ having the finite intersection property, you have $\bigcap_{C \in \mathscr{C}} C \neq \varnothing $.

And your ascending chain collection has the finite intersection property.

Comment: Properly speaking the finite intersection property is a property of families of sets, not of spaces, compact or otherwise. What you mean is the characterization of compactness in terms of families of closed sets with the FIP.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use the finite intersection property (which is a rephrasing of what you are trying to do).